# Not able to Import tags in text area on radiobox selection in dynatree

Tags: jquery, tags, dynatree

I am using tags input jquery plugin. I have a set of categories shown in a tree format with the help of `dynatree`.
On select of a category through the radio box in the `dynatree` I want to  "import" tags into the text area. I am not able to code is as below:

**JS Code:**

```
onSelect:function (select,node){
   var s=node.tree.getSelectedNodes().join(", ");
   $("form#myformId .tagsinput").importtags("guava");
  },
  ....
  ....
});
```

**JSP Code:**

```
<script ..... /jquery.tagsinput.is"></script>
<div class="" id="mytags">
<textarea name="tags" id="tagsId">
<textarea/>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your line :

```
$("form#myformId .tagsinput").importtags("guava");
```

With this one:

```
$("form#myformId #tagsId").importtags("guava");
```

Comment: That won't work. Vijay, tagsinput plugin dynamically updates the div I'd. Already tried that :(